# Android webview cannot download files

Tags: android, android-webview

i am working with one HTML application. which i had browse in webview now that site will allow to download PDF file. 
Now issue is that when load that URL in device browser it will download PDF file automaticaly but in webview cannot download that file i had used below code.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new webChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,String contentDisposition, String mimetype,long contentLength) {
          AppLog.logString(TAG+"setDownloadListener");
          AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);
          //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          //intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          //startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);

private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  
    String TAG="ClBk: ";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);

        if(!isInternetOncheck()){
            intenetDialog();
        }else{

            boolean value = true;  
            String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);  
            AppLog.logString(TAG+"extension: "+extension);
            if (extension != null) {  
                 MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();  
                 String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                 AppLog.logString(TAG+"mimeType: "+mimeType);
                 if (mimeType != null) {  
                      if (mimeType.contains("application/zip")
                                ||mimeType.toLowerCase().contains("video")  
                                || extension.toLowerCase().contains("mov")  
                                || extension.toLowerCase().contains("mp3")) {
                           AppLog.logString(TAG+"If MimeType for dowloading");
                           DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);  
                           DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));  
                           File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),getFileName(url,extension));  
                           request.setDescription("Downloading via Your app name..");  
                           request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  
                           request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));  
                           mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);  
                           value = false;  
                      }  
                 }  
            }  
            if(url.contains(".pdf")){
            AppLog.logString(TAG+"pdf");
            view.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                    AppLog.logString(TAG+"download pdf");
                    startDownloadPDF(url);
                }
            });
            }else if(url.contains(".rar")){
                AppLog.logString(TAG+"rar");
                view.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                        AppLog.logString(TAG+"download rar");
                        startDownloadZBS(url);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                AppLog.logString(TAG+"else: "+url);
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"onPageStarted");
        //AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(!isInternetOncheck()){
            intenetDialog();
        }
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }   
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"onPageFinished");
        //AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutSplace)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }   
 }
```

In browser when url dowload pdf file it dowloading in this url (http:/......../rptTrialBalance/ExporttoPDF?dtSession1=PDFReport&FileName=TrialBa‌​lance&download=true) in browser it download but webview cannot download this

i had already check this url it's not working [How to use a download Manager in a webview to download pdf/ppt/doc files to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786275/how-to-use-a-download-manager-in-a-webview-to-download-pdf-ppt-doc-files-to-sdca)

Comment: can u give me th url so that i can try at my end?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864098/how-to-download-files-from-webview-android see this link once

Comment: @Venu sorry it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Chrome CLient for this.

```
//webExternalLinks is your webview.

    webExternalLinks.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    if(seekBar==null){
                        seekBar = IjoomerUtilities
                                .getLoadingDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_loading_please_wait));
                    }
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if(progress==100){
                        seekBar=null;
                    }
                }
            });

            webExternalLinks.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webExternalLinks.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webExternalLinks.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            webExternalLinks.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webExternalLinks.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            if (link != null && link.length() > 0) {
                if (!link.startsWith("http://") && !link.startsWith("https://")) {
                    link = "http://" + link;
                }
                webExternalLinks.loadUrl(link);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

try this one:
first of all ,plz print Url which you passed in URI.and open that URL in Browser.is it open or not?
if it is not open in browswer then problem getting url.

Comment: sorry this is session base dowloading we cannot open that url in other browser its destroy session. i want to dowload file in my own webview

Comment: @PankajAndroid chk this one...
http://call-me-early.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-webview-download-pdf-generated.html

Answer (score 0):

From a breif looking, you don't identify the pdf download as your condition is 
url.contains(".pdf")
but your URL doesn't contain this string.
you should somehow get the content type returned in the response header content-type.
Hope that helps.
Nitzan